# Batch File Syntax Error

Tags: batch-file

**Current Output**

When 1 or 2 as input a list is returned.

**Desired Output**

The following code should identify if the code exists or not.

**Code:**

```
@echo off
TITLE Air Access Reader
color 0f

:menu
cls
color 0f
echo Welcome to Air Access Code Reader!
echo.
echo 1) Check for existing code.
echo 2) Check the list of people.
echo.
set /p "op1=>"

if op1 EQU 1 goto existing
if op1 EQU 2 goto list

:existing
cls
echo Enter whole code:
echo.
set /p "code=>"

if code EQU 1244-8766-9901-8136 goto exists
color 0c
echo Sorry, this code doens't exists. Please try re-writing it.
echo.
pause
cls
goto menu

:list
cls
echo.
echo Registred card codes from Air group:
echo.
echo -  1244-8766-9901-8136  []  Gabriel Spalato  []  CEO and Founder
echo. 
echo.
pause
goto menu

:exists
if code EQU 1244-8766-9901-8136 set say= Gabriel Spalato  []  CEO and    Founder
goto show

:show
cls
echo.
echo Code inserted: %code%
echo.
echo =====================================================================
echo.
echo Registred card code found:
echo.
echo -  %code%  []  %say%
echo.
pause 
goto menu
```

Comment: I invite you to use question titles that briefly describe the problem you have. I used to not read questions with titles like this one, but I open it after I realized that you posted _two similar questions_ in a few minutes...

Comment: Ok then, i'll try to make titles, because i'm not good at creating titles for things..

Answer (score 2):

```
if op1 EQU 1 goto ...
```

The string `op1` will never be the same as the string `1`. You want to compare the variable `%op1%`:

```
if "%op1%" EQU "1" goto ...
```

the quotes are not absolutely neccessary, but prevents from syntax errors, if the variable should be empty or contain spaces.

Comment: But now, when i input the correct code it say's the code is wrong!

Comment: I solved, thanks for helping out..